# I suspect my employer filled and signed my W-4

Tags: united-states, employment, taxes

My employer didn't give me a W-4 to fill in on my first day of employment. My paycheck stubs list withholding amounts and a number for the dependents I'm claiming. I'm assuming my supervisor or HR filled in the form for me. The amounts and dependents listed are incorrect. What can I do?

To clarify, A W-4 is a standard form an employee lists their number of dependents and withholding dollars for tax purposes in the US. Most employers have their new employees fill one in the first day they work for the company. If no W-4 is submitted the standard deductions are listed.

Comment: What is W4? What is withholdings and number of depends? How is W4 related to W2? What did you assume he signed, and how did you arrive at this conclusion? Please be more clear with your question.

Comment: seems odd considering your signature is required on those forms - https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf - are you sure you didn't sign this and just hand it over blank? Otherwise, the implication here is that they forged your signature. Or maybe they can submit electronically without your signature on the physical form. I'm not a lawyer - might want to contact a tax attorney

Comment: I never signed anything. I was never given paper work. Yes the number of dependents are more then I would have put down and my marital status is on my check stub also. I'm going to talk to the owner.

Comment: You can't fill out a W4 online

Comment: The employer will have a default value for it's withholding.  Not signing one doesn't mean they won't withhold, it just means you didn't get an opportunity to direct that withholding.

Comment: What's with the down votes? This is a legit question. Just because YOU don't know what a W4 is doesn't mean this isn't a good question. Not all employees know what they must do when starting a new job. It is also the responsibility of the employer to give these forms to the employee. He's in the dark and asking for help, not whining.

Comment: @Andieisme I am sure it is a great question, but it is not clear what it is referring to. If you know it better, you should edit the question to make it clear to those who don't. Nobody said he is whining, the close reason is pretty clear in that regard. Also when I cast my close vote, there was no country tag here, and this being an international site, you shouldn't berate people for not knowing what a W4 means.

Comment: @MaskedMan - the question is clear, to me. If someone doesn't know what forms he's talking about it just means that person doesn't know what he's talking about. LOL Not sure how else to explain it. It still doesn't make it a bad question. I'll see what I can do about editing it.

Comment: @Andieisme The edit that you made was all that is needed. "If someone doesn't know what forms he's talking about it just means that person doesn't know what he's talking about." This was not necessary. It is clear to you does not mean it is clear to everyone, you should not assume that everyone lives in the US.

Comment: @MaskedMan - again, just because you (general you) doesn't know what a form is doesn't mean it's a bad question. I certainly don't know what some of the references to CVs (kinda like a resume, but not) are all about, that doesn't mean it's a bad question when someone asks, it means I won't have an answer. So, the down votes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

The irs has a tax topic related to this:

[Topic 753 - Form W-4 – Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc753.html)

> When you hire an employee, you must have the employee complete a Form
>   W-4 (PDF), Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate. Form W-4
>   tells you, as the employer, the marital status, the number of
>   withholding allowances, and any additional amount to use when you
>   deduct federal income tax from the employee's pay. If an employee
>   fails to give you a properly completed Form W-4, you must withhold
>   federal income taxes from his or her wages as if he or she were single
>   and claiming no withholding allowances.

So if you never turned in a W-4, they should set it to single and no withholding allowances, which will result in the maximum amount of federal taxes withheld.

The good news is that you can submit a new form (as well as the state version of the form) at any time. So calculate what it should be, and then submit it. In a paycheck or two you should see the change.

W-4s, health insurance forms, 401K and direct deposit forms are very important forms that you should get into the habit of submitting in the first few days or even the first few hours of a new job.

Comment: And in the future, if you do not see such forms, ask about them within the first two days of a job.If they tool out too little, you will owe taxes at the end of the year (so either start saving or fill out the new W4 to have a bit more taken out than you need depending on how long this has been going on.) and if they took out too much, you can't get it back until you fill out taxes.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to talk to your employer or HR on this one.  They are either withholding taxes or not and if you didn't specify a specific amount of withholding then they might have a default selection for all their employees.

Discuss with HR and there should be a way to adjust the amount withheld to match the W4 criteria you would normally select.

Comment: You can submit a new W-4 to change the amount withheld at any time.